# Assigning unsinged int (with .size()) to 1D float vector

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, unsigned-integer, size-type

I am a complete newbie in programming and my question might be completely trivial to you. I tried a lot but just could not figure out why this program is **not giving me an error**. This code is part of one of the exercise I have been doing. Part of the code here is to assign number of rows in vector `vec1` to variable `rows`

When I assign a `unsigned int` (with `.size()`) to a 1D float vector, it should give me an error, right? The exercise is using this code and its running fine. I am wondering what I am missing to understand.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  //declaring a float 1D vector
  std::vector<float> vec1(4,0); 
  //declaring new variable 'row' - Type float - 1D vector
  std::vector<float>::size_type rows;
  
  rows = vec1.size(); // this should give me error because i am assigning a unsigned int(with .size()) to row - 'float 1d vector'.
  
  std::cout<<rows<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<float>::size_type`  is not a vector, it is the type that `std::vector::size` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector::size_type` is the type of the variable that stores the size of the container. What you want is `std::vector::value_type`. Even then it will compile because an `unsigned int` can be assigned to a `float`.

Comment: I see, that makes lot of sense. Thanks @krisz for excellent explanation! So, i found this explanation somewhere, **"declare rows as a variable of a type suitable for holding the biggest possible size of a vector system can hold"**, is that right way to put it then?

Comment: Yes, that quote describes what this line of code does: `std::vector<float>::size_type rows;`.